# Как сделать Materialize CSS side-nav с двумя кнопками в 1 линии?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, material-design, materialize-css

Необходимо разделить ссылки `<li>` в боковой панели (`.side-nav`) фреймворка Materialize CSS на отдельные части.
Например, чтобы было слово (линк на страницу статьи) и следом в той же линии иконка "+" (например, линк на создание новой статьи).

[Как вот здесь](https://iz.zohostatic.com/sites/default/files/online-contact-manager_0.png), "Contacts", а рядом "+".

```
<ul class="side-nav fixed>
  <li>
    <a href="#!">Sidebar Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Страница компонента.](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)

Comment: В чем именно проблема? как насчет "начального кода" ?

Comment: добавил, но там фреймфорк

Comment: Как насчет использования ::after? Если подходи такой вариант (просто не знаком с этим фреймворком), то добавлю ответ.